# Exported function symbol name mangling

Tags: dll, export, d, name-mangling

I have a D DLL that is being loaded by a C++ program that I have no control over. The program LoadLibrarys my DLL and uses GetProcAddress to find a function named "extension_load" that takes one argument (a pointer). In my D DLL I have:

```
extern (C) int extension_load(void* ptr) {
    return 0;
}
```

And this name needs to be exported as extension_load but it is being exported as extension_load@4, so GetProcAddress cannot find it. How do I make it plain extension_load without the name mangling?

Comment: And does GetProcAddress *not* find the function? Where does the `extension_load@4` come from (ie. how did you find out it was this name)?

Comment: @jpalecek, Sorry, I thought it was implied. GetProcAddress fails to find the function by the name of extension_load. The @4 comes from the length in bytes of all the arguments, and I know extension_load@4 is what it's being exported as now because if I open the process with a debugger and modify the string in memory to be extension_load@4, the function is found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to provide the linker with a .def file that renames the export.  Docs [are here](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/ctgDefFiles.html), you need EXPORTS.

Comment: I'm brand new to D and I have no idea how to provide the linker with a .def file that renames the export. I don't even know the command line options.

Comment: Well, consider it a great opportunity to start learning more about it.  Your question isn't detailed enough for me to tell if you use some kind of IDE or build by hand.  Browse the site I linked to, it has docs on the linker as well.

Answer (score 4):

I got it working with some help from Hans Passant's link. Here is my .def file for anyone who will need it in the future (probably myself too):

```
EXETYPE NT

EXPORTS
    extension_load
    DllMain
```

The .def file I have is named dll.def. I have the function written as:

```
extern (C++) int extension_load(void* ptr) {
```

and the IDE I use is D-IDE, so to give the linker the def file, go to Project > Properties > Build Options and type

```
nameofdef.def
```

in the Extra Linking arguments text box. This assumes that the nameofdef.def file exists in your main project directory for D-IDE to find.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need for a def file. Just prepend your functions with `export`, e.g.:

```
    export extern (C) int extension_load(void* ptr) {
    return 0;
}
```

And compile via: `dmd -ofmydll.dll mydll.d`. Of course you'll need to define `DllMain()` as well.